# HTTPS and HTTP connection in java

Tags: java, http, url, httpurlconnection

I know that HTTPS extends http. So does that mean i can do this?

```
HttpUrlConnection connect = passmyurl.openconnection(url);
```

and

```
HttpsUrlConnection connect = passmyurl.openconnection(url);



public static HttpsURLConnection passmyurl(URL url) throws IOException {
        HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        return connection;
    }
```

Does this mean that both will work? Since the HTTps extends HTTP, it means I can also pass a HTTP url to this function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code:

```
public static HttpsURLConnection passmyurl(URL url) throws IOException {
    HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    return connection;
}
```

You should change the return type `HttpsURLConnection` to `URLConnection`.Because the `url.openConnection()` result's type is subtype of `URLConnection`,and the exact type depends on the paramter `url`'s protocol.The implemention document of `openConnection()` in the `URL` class:

```
If for the URL's protocol (such as HTTP or JAR), there exists a public, specialized URLConnection subclass belonging to one of the following packages or one of their subpackages: java.lang, java.io, java.util, java.net, the connection returned will be of that subclass. For example, for HTTP an HttpURLConnection will be returned, and for JAR a JarURLConnection will be returned.
```

So you can pass the `Http` url or `Https` url to your method.

See the following code:

```
    URLConnection httpConnection = new URL("http://test").openConnection();
    System.out.println(httpConnection.getClass());
    URLConnection httpsConnection = new URL("https://test").openConnection();
    System.out.println(httpsConnection.getClass());
    URLConnection ftpConnection = new URL("ftp://test").openConnection();
    System.out.println(ftpConnection.getClass());`
```

the print is:

```
class sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection
class sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl
class sun.net.www.protocol.ftp.FtpURLConnection
```